# how to insert dynamically created label text into sql server in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

It shows no error,

but the values didn't insert into sql server.....

how can we access the dynamically generated Labels and checkboxes in the Wizard_buttonClick() from the EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged()

```
    protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;
            newcheck.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckBox_CheckedChanged);

            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }  
    }

    protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

        var label = Labeldiv.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
        var checkbox = Labeldiv.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into EventDays(EventDay,EventStatus)values(@EventDay,@EventStatus)", con))
        {
            var paramDay = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventDay", SqlDbType.DateTime);
            var paramStatus = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventStatus", SqlDbType.Int);
            if (label != null)
            {
                paramDay.Value = label;
                paramStatus.Value = checkbox.Checked ? 1 : 0;
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Please clarify your question ?

Comment: Same comment as of @DavidPilkington and also if you are executing this code did you got any error?,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is shown because you add the parameters several times in the loop. Parameter names must be unique.
Change your code so that the parameters are created out of the loop and the values are set in the loop:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into EventDays(EventDay,EventStatus)values(@EventDay,@EventStatus)", con))
{
    var paramDay = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventDay", SqlDbType.DateTime);
    var paramStatus = cmd2.Parameters.Add("@EventStatus", SqlDbType.Int);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Label NewLabel = new Label();
        NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;

        var eventDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(i);
        NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();
        NewLabel.CssClass = "h1size";

        CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
        newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;

        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
        this.Checkboxdiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
        this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));

        paramDay.Value = eventDate;
        paramStatus.Value = newCheck.Checked ? 1 : 0;
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The sample assumes that EventDate is a DateTime and EventStatus is an Int, you might need to adjust the data types. Depending on how many times you execute the command, you could run cmd2.[Prepare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)() after you added the parameters. 
In addition, the using statement assures that the SqlCommand object is disposed in a proper way.

Comment: Thank You, @Markus, but I have another doubt...................

Comment: Can I access the variables paramDay, paramStatus in another class i.e. Button_Click event ..??

Comment: In this implementation, paramDay and paramStatus are variables on method level. You can only access them in this method. From your code above I suppose that you want to show the same reaction in EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged and CheckBox_CheckedChanged. For that, you'd have to move the code from EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged to a separate method and also include the connection and command (that is now located in CheckBox_CheckedChanged). You'd call the method from both events then.

Comment: I want to create the Labels and CheckBoxes dynamically in EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged. After that I want to store those values into sql server after Button click event or Checkbox_CheckedChanged event.

Comment: In Checkbox_CheckedChanged event, you can use LabelDiv.FindControl with the label's id ("Label" + number) as a parameter to find the corresponding label.

Comment: could u atleast give one line code.....

Comment: var label = LabelDiv.FindControl("Label1") as Label; if (label != null) // Do something;

Comment: I edit my Question as u said, please check and one error occurs i.e. " Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Just guessing: as you add several labels and checkboxes, you might want to store all of their values in the database. So you'd need to also add a loop in the code that executes the database commands. After all the effort for the dynamic approach, I'd suggest to also think about whether there is a sensible maximum number of labels and create them in the designer. Instead of accessing them dynamically - which leads to lots of problems if we look at the history of the question, use the Visible property of the controls to show or hide them.

Comment: Is there any solution to my problem while dynamic creation???

Comment: Yes, I think so; but the dynamic approach is way more complex than a solution based on the designer. So before trying to solve a real-world problem this way, you should have a good understanding how dynamic control creation and handling works in ASP.NET. I suggest you first read on this topic (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178511(v=vs.100).aspx and other articles), then create a separate project that does not contain data access and all the other distracting stuff and implement the basic dynamic approach. Once this works, transfer it to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

What if you move the

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into EventDays(EventDay,EventStatus)values(@EventDay,@EventStatus)", con);
```

inside the loop?

Change

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventStatus", newcheck.Checked ?? 1:0);
```

Comment: And you can try adding the i value to the end of the param name so it's unique. Just giving some ideas.

Comment: Thank you, but "Monday, January 01, 0001" is also inserted in a seperated row into sql server along with selected date....

Comment: I want to insert checkbox value as bit (0- on, 1-off) into sql server

Comment: Does it happen outside the loop?

Comment: You cant add checkbox.check then

Comment: It will try to add the checkbox text, not the value

Comment: Try something like that, instead of newcheck.Text use newcheck.checked ?? 1 :0, if it's checked it will try to add 1, if not(case false), it will try to add 0

Comment: Added an example to code

Comment: newcheck.checked??1:0  or  newcheck.checked?1:0